# Convergence in probability of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ when $X_i$'s are i.i.d $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

**Question:**

[image]

**My approach:**

[image]

And after this I am stuck..How do I put the modulus over here and how do I determine the appropriate value of "k" ?
 (here k signifies the value of convergence in probability for n tendig to infinity).

Comment: Hint: $E[X_i^2]=1$.

Comment: Should we use WLLN ? In that case expectation is easy to find(as you've directed) but how to deal with Var( sum X_i^2) ? Can you please ellaborate..

Comment: Further hint: $\sum X_i^2$ is a $\chi_n^2$ random variable and so you should be able to look up its variance in a textbook or on-line etc.

Comment: @DB why do you think you need $var (\sum X_i^2)$? You can findt it using the chi-squared distribution or rules about the variance of a sum of independent variables but why would you need it?

Comment: @Martijn By using Markovs WLLN(as X_i's are iid Chebyshevs also do)  if   Var( sum X_i^2)/n^2->0 then  ( [(sum X_i^2)-E(sumX_i^2)]/n->0(in probabiliy) i.e (1/n)( sum X_i^2) ->E(sumX_i^2)..

Comment: That is what the question asks for i guess..so..is it okay?

Comment: @DB I believe that you are confusing the Weak Law of Large Numbers with Markov's inequality (or did Markov give some specific version of it?). The latter can be used to proof the former (and you do not need the *exact* variances for this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650105/466748). But why would you not just start with the WLLN (only making assumptions about the first moment) instead of Markov's inequality (see Dilip's hint)?

Comment: Yes..The Markovs inequality i used previosly is not needed..i understand what you said..Only WLLN will do..

Comment: @DB You can post your own solution based on comments and accept any one of the answers to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i:= X_i^2-\mathbb E\left[X_i^2\right]=X_i^2-1$.  Then 
$$
\Pr\left\{\frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon\right\}=\Pr\left\{\frac 1{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)^2\gt \varepsilon^2\right\}
\leqslant \frac 1{n^2\varepsilon^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)^2\right].
$$
To continue, we expand  the square as $\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)^2=  \sum_{i=1}^nY_i ^2+\sum_{i,j=1,j\neq i}^nY_iY_j$. The following tasks are remaining:

- control of $n^{-2}\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nY_i ^2\right]$;
- control of $n^{-2}\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i,j=1,j\neq i}^nY_iY_j\right]$ (hint: the random variables $Y_i$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$ are independent and centered).

Comment: The hints in the comments to the question point towards a much simpler way of obtaining the answer: the expression is a sequence of averages of independent identically distributed random variables. Their common expectation is readily found. A cautious student might spend a few more seconds to check that these variables have a finite variance, but by then the answer will be clear to all.

Comment: @whuber From the comment I understood the suggestion of the direct application of the weak law of large numbers. But I thought the opening poster would also be interested in a direct approach, in the spirit of his/her attempt.

Comment: I read it a little differently: because it's a multiple choice question, a rigorous detailed demonstration isn't needed.  One just has to show how to arrive at the correct answer, preferably with a minimum of time and effort.  Although there's nothing wrong with your approach, it seems unnecessary to expand squares and do all that algebra when all that matters is that the $X_i^2$ are iid with known mean and finite variance.